# Does $\alpha^{\omega}$ have a countable fixed point $\alpha>1$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

In ordinal arithmetic, does the function $f(\alpha)=\alpha^{\omega}$ have a fixed point which is countable and greater than 1? I think the answer is "no", as I've tried quite hard to construct examples, but I do not understand how to use the countability. Really, I would like to prove $\alpha$ countable implies $\alpha < \alpha^{\omega}$ for $\alpha >1$. I can do this via an induction but I don't see how to treat the case where $\alpha$ is a limit.

I would appreciate guidance in how to show that functions defined by arithmetic operations on ordinals have no countable fixed point more generally.

Comment: One pointer is that if you want $f(x)>x$ for all ordinal $x$ then there is  a proper class  $C$ of limit ordinals such that $x\in C\implies f(x)>\sup \{f(y): y<x\}.$ So with the order-topology on $x+1$, if $x\in C$ then $f$ is not  continuous on ${x+1}$....  A "relative" of this is that if $f:\omega_1\to \omega_1$ is continuous with respect to the order topology on $\omega_1$ and if $f(x)\geq x$ for all $x$ then $\{x\in \omega_1:f(x)=x\}$ is closed and uncountable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. There are none. To see why, note that there is a monotonicity here: $$\alpha<\alpha\cdot\alpha=\alpha^2<\dots<\alpha^\omega,$$
for any $\alpha>1$.

To prove this, simply note that $\alpha+1<\alpha^2$ as well. And therefore $\alpha$ is a proper initial segment of $\alpha^2$, and thus of $\alpha^\omega$.

As a final remark, see that the above doesn't even use the fact that $\alpha$ is countable.

Comment: Whoops - I was about to say that the limit of the sequence $f(2), f(f(2)),\dots$ must be a fixed point. Evidently $f$ is not continuous...

Comment: OK, I agree with the sufficiency of showing $\alpha < \alpha^2$. You're saying "note $\alpha+1<\alpha^2$" and that is because you define $\alpha^2$ to be the sup of $\alpha, \alpha 2,...$ and $\alpha +1$ is less than $\alpha n$ for $n$ finite. That's true because they're not equal (one's a successor, the other's a limit) and $\alpha + 1 > \alpha n$ implies $\alpha = \alpha n$ and that implies $\alpha$ is 0 by arguing about addition, right?

Comment: @probablystuck: Yes, in a nutshell, that is the argument if you want to get down to brass tacks.

Answer (score 0):

For ordinals $a,b$ let $S(a,b)$ be the set of functions $f:b\to a$ such that $\{x\in b:f(x)\ne 0\}$ is finite. Give $S(a,b)$ the reverse-lexicographic order: If $f,g\in S(a,b)$ and $y=\max \{x\in b: f(x)\ne g(x)\}$ then $f<g$ iff $f(y)<g(y).$ This is a well-order.

$a^b$ is defined to be the unique ordinal  that is order-isomorphic to this order on $S(a,b).$

It is straightforward to show that  if $a>1$ and $b_1<b_2$ then  $S(a,b_1)$ is a proper initial segment of $S(a,b_2),$ and therefore $a^{b_1}<a^{b_2}.$

For example, if $a>1$ then $a<a^2<a^3<....<a^{\omega}.$